# how can i fix this this fatal exception in my android code?

Tags: android

I've written a class with `textSplitter` and some code in MainActivity.java
But I'm getting a fatal runtime exception.

```
public class textSplitter {

    public String myText(BufferedReader bufferedReader,StringBuilder stringBuilder,String line,String fin) throws IOException {

        while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append('\n');
        }
        fin = stringBuilder.toString();
        return fin;
    }

    public String[] txtConverter(String[] text,String fin) {
        text = fin.split("\\$");
        return text;
    }
}
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.text1);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        String fin = null;
        String[] text = null;
        textSplitter myClass = new textSplitter();
        try {
            myClass.myText(br,stringBuilder,line,fin);
            myClass.txtConverter(text,fin);

            TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
            myText.setText(text.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use logcat to get a stack trace so you know at least what line to look at and what type of error is involved.

Comment: in my logcat: '03-16 01:23:43.479    2351-2369/com.example.sadeq.sadeq1 W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-16 01:23:43.480    2351-2369/com.example.sadeq.sadeq1 W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6ccc280, error=EGL_SUCCESS'

Comment: Those "errors" are not the problem.  Annoying but not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
myClass.myText(br,stringBuilder,line,fin);
```

Because you never set the value of `fin` to the results. 
Try

```
fin = myClass.myText(br,stringBuilder,line,fin);
```

This should avoid your NPE when you do

```
text = fin.split("\\$");
```

Comment: yes. i forget this. thank you, But my app  before run show this error message : failed to complete Gradle Execution. Cause; A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit

Comment: yes. i forget this. thank you, But my app before run show this error message : failed to complete Gradle Execution. Cause; A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit

Comment: Would you like to share you gradle build output?